# Biblatex in Mac

Tags: biblatex, mac

everyone!

For a long time, I have been using **bibtex** for generate bibliography in my docs. Now, i am trying to migrate to **biblatex** in Mac.

I have followed the steps to generate a bibliography, that seems to be straightforward like the bibtex. So, for a simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}

% ---------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
    hyperref = true,
    backref = true,
    ]{biblatex}

\bibliography{biblio}
% ---------------------------
\begin{document}

\cite{you2016}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

When compiling, the result is:

[image]

Compiling bibtex in Texshop, I always get the same error:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
The top-level auxiliary file: Sem-Título.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file Sem-Título.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Sem-Título.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Sem-Título.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Using the **bibtex** package, I get the expected result. What would the solution be for using **biblatex**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to compile with Biber and not BibTeX. See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) as well as [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).

Comment: I voted to close your question as a duplicate, since your answer is already included in the answers to the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Just inserting the following code:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
```

at the top of the document make it works.